# How to rotate to a specific point when a game object rotating in vector3.forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

[My player is the cube and the target is sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTP8G.jpg)

```
`void Update()

{

    Vector3 direction = target.position - player.transform.position;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);


    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))

    {

        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(player.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(player.transform.rotation.x, player.transform.rotation.y, rotation.z), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    else

    {

        player.transform.Rotate(-Vector3.forward * 1f);
    }

}
`
```

Player is rotating infinitely like a spherically movement with transform rotate. When I click I want to rotate my player to target position. I'm trying with rotate towards but its rotating to 0. How can I fix this problem or should I do with something else.

Comment: @derHugo what should I use . When my object rotating around itself I think I need know which degree in my game object currently. So I can move to do specific degree that I want. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @derHugo I am sorry for not being clear. My player rotating only on the z axis(-Vector3.Forward). But I have a game object that I set as a target. Normally the player spins on its own. But when I click, I want the player to rotate softly to the position where the target is, no matter where the current position is. When the target rotation complete . My player going to rotate only on z axis again where it end up the target rotation.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all: The x, y, z of a `Quaternion` are not what you expect them to be! They have nothing to do with Euler angles and move in normalized ranges between `-1` and `1`.

Then assuming you rotate the `player` **only** ever on the Z axis then you could simply use e.g.

```
void Update()
{
    // use Vector2 to eliminate any delta on the Z axis
    // -> vector is only in XY space
    Vector2 direction = target.position - player.transform.position;
    // -> rotation is only on Z axis
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(player.transform.rotation, rotation), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        player.transform.Rotate(-Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```